# How to get access to computer files for development through Android Emulator

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

My problem is that I'm using parse.com to upload files, and I can't simply create a java project to do so, because it requires an Android context:

```
Parse.initialize(this, "", "");
```

I was wondering if there was a work around to access my computer's files through an Android emulator. I know the ACTUAL app technically wouldn't have any idea of my files, but the emulator is still running on my computer. Or is the emulator completely independent to near-perfectly imitate the real thing, and basically this would be impossible?

If the answer is no, what can I do aside from getting a phone and putting the files onto the phone?

Comment: I think answer is No.And you can push your files to emulator by using ddms

Comment: Keep in mind you can use the data browser to upload files from your computer, too.

Comment: a very inefficient way though, i have multiple files i need to upload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Parse.com REST API](https://parse.com/docs/rest) to upload from anywhere.

The Parse API for Android is just a wrapper for this REST API.

There are also some existing Pure Java wrappers for the REST API by third parties. See the Java section of the [Parse API Library page.](https://parse.com/docs/api_libraries) [Almonds](https://bitbucket.org/jskrepnek/almonds) in particular looks to give you what you want.